# Logarithmic scale in plotly boxplot on logged data

Tags: scale, r-plotly, ggplotly

I want to create a boxplot (and potentially other plots) with logarithmic scale AND statistics calculated on logged data. The following example shows the logic.

The data looks like:

```
d1 <- data.frame(x = rchisq(1000, 2), mod = c(rep('a', 500), rep('b', 500)))
```

If I pre-transform data, I obtain the plot with the value of logs on y-axis.

```
plot_ly(d1, y = ~log10(x), color = ~mod, type = 'box')
```

[image]

If I transform y-axis after creating boxplot, I get a boxplot with the length of whiskers and median from the original data and the original data in log scale on y-axis.

```
plot_ly(d1, y = ~x, color = ~mod, type = 'box') %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(type = "log", showgrid=T,  ticks="outside", autorange=TRUE))
```

[image]

My desirable outcome is a combination of the 2 plots above - the boxplot from the first picture and the scale from the second one. It should look like something that is possible to do in ggplot:

```
d1 %>% ggplot(aes(y=x, alpha = 0.1, color = mod, fill = mod))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

I tried to use ggploly to modify ggplot into plotly, but it loses the scale and changes it to the scale from the first picture.

Can anybody help with making such a plot in plotly or how to preserve the log-scale on y-axis with ggplotly?

Answer (score 2):

It is harder to maintain the log scale when you transform a `ggplot` object to `ggplotly` - for box plot.  You were very close in `plot_ly`.  Just add `tickvals=c(0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10)` to the layout of your `plot_ly` and you will get the following output:

[image: output]

You can figure out the range of your data and define appropriately as a vector `mytickvals<-c(1,10,100)`, and then in layout assign it as `tickvals=mytickvals`.

Comment: Well, it does not solve the problem - the boxplot itself (I mean outliers, quantiles, etc.) are the same as at the second plot at the original post, while they needed to be as at the first one.

Comment: As you have negative values for y in first plot, it will be difficult to display a log scale for y-axis.  Also, please note the issue of transforming variables prior to summarizing as noted in https://coolbutuseless.github.io/2018/08/06/ggplot2-stat_summary-problem/.